# Data Recovery on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery, recovery

I recently purchased a new computer so that I could upgrade my old Linux machine. My old machine was running Ubuntu 16.04 Server LTS. The operating system was installed on a 256 GB SSD, while a single 7 TB HDD was used for data storage. Like the SSD disk, the data drive was connected to the system via SATA. In other words, the data drive is not an external USB drive.

On the new system I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 Server LTS on a new 1TB SSD drive. Then, I physically moved the 7 TB HDD from my old machine and connected it to the new system. However, to much surprise previously stored data on the old 7 TB HDD is now missing, that is, Ubuntu 18.04 is reporting that the disk does not contain any information, meaning it does not show any files or directories. Ubuntu displays 7 TB of free space.

Of course, I have not repartitioned the drive or written any data to the it. All I have done is to physically connect the old drive to the new machine and boot Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The file system used is ext4.

What is going on and how can I recovery my data?

I have tried tools like testdisk, photorec etc., but with no luck.

Here is some output:

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/loop0: 86.9 MiB, 91099136 bytes, 177928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 89.5 MiB, 93818880 bytes, 183240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 89.5 MiB, 93835264 bytes, 183272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: XXX

Device           Start         End     Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         2048 15628052479 15628050432   7.3T Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  15628052480 15628053134         655 327.5K Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdc: 1.9 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: XXX

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdc2   4096 4000794623 4000790528  1.9T Linux filesystem
```

Here is what Foremost reports:

```
Invocation: foremost -i /dev/sda1 -t png -o /home/erran/foremost
File: /dev/sda1
Start: Thu Jan 10 13:55:00 2019
Length: 7 TB (8001561821184 bytes)

Num      Name (bs=512)         Size      File Offset     Comment

Finish: Fri Jan 11 02:27:21 2019

0 FILES EXTRACTED
```

More output based on suggestion from @agc:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda count=1 bs=1G | gzip -1 | wc -c
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 8.43023 s, 127 MB/s
7332366

sudo dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=1G | gzip -1 | wc -c
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 4.16624 s, 258 MB/s
4683762
```

Comment: Can you move the 7 TB HDD back to the old machine to see if the data reappears?

Comment: I guess I could do that, but since there is some effort involved in this process I would like to solve this without going through the hassle of taking out the drive, reconnecting it to the old machine etc.

Comment: Did the old machine have one volume spanning both physical disks perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried Foremost?

Comment: See: [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/q/241817/87805)

Comment: Can you post some command outputs what you've tried with `testdisk`?

Comment: Just a SATA cable going from the HDD directly to the motherboard. No USB-bridge involved now. No RAID-kontroller. I have not enabled any encryption, unless this is default in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server.

Comment: I have not tried foremost, but will give it a shot now.

Comment: I only pasted the information about the data disk. If it helps I can paste the output of the OS disk as well. Foremost is running now and I will update the post with the output of that when it is done.

Comment: What does "the disk does not contain any information and that the disk has 7.3 TB of free space" mean? The `fdisk` output says it contains *at least* the partition table. What happens when you `mount -o ro /dev/sda1 /mnt/whatever`? If it mounts and the data is not there at all, then maybe it is elsewhere, like on the old SSD. How much data is supposed to be there? Is the following scenario plausible? The HDD was (by mistake) never mounted in the old OS and all the data ended up in `/alleged/mountpoint/but/not/really` on the old SSD.

Comment: At this point, it is too late to say to not do anything to the 7 TB HDD. I suggest that it is worth the effort to put it back in the old computer - if the data reappears then we can check what adjustments need to be made for the disk to work in the new computer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Updated my original post to answer your questions. How can 7 TB (the 7TB disk was full) of data be stored on a 256GB SSD or "elsewhere"?

Comment: `How can 7 TB (the 7TB disk was full) of data be stored on a 256GB SSD or "elsewhere"?` -- You didn't tell us how much data was there. You didn't say there was no other storage (that might by "elsewhere"). Considering the information you provided my scenario was at least plausible.

Answer (score 0):

Don't panic... it takes a **long time** to erase a 7 TB hard disk.

Take a minute to check if the data's *really* gone, by compressing the first Gigabyte of the whole disk with `gzip -1`, and comparing the size.  For example, using my current working hard drive:

```
dd if=/dev/sda count=1 bs=1G | gzip -1 | wc -c
```

Output, after a minute:

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 54.3403 s, 19.8 MB/s
1072079878
```

The last number *1072079878* is the compressed size, which is quite close to the uncompressed size.  Partly this is because `gzip -1` goes fast and doesn't compress very well, and partly it's because the first gigabyte of `/dev/sda` has plenty of data in it.

Compare that to the same code, but using */dev/zero*, (an endless stream of zeros):

```
dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=1G | gzip -1 | wc -c
```

Output, (runs in under 10 seconds):

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 8.65898 s, 124 MB/s
4683762
```

Since the data is all zeros, even `gzip -1` can compress *1G* down to *4M*, (less than *1%* of the original size).

Assuming there's no malware involved, then only if your hard drive shows a compression ratio that resembles compressing */dev/zero*, (and only if it did so on *both* computers), would there be something to worry about.  Otherwise, it's probably some *BIOS* config inconsistency...

Comment: To check the *whole* disk, (which hopefully wouldn't be necessary), remove the `count=1` option from `dd`.  Yalla!